# With Pytest, is it possible to get coverage information from sub-process ran by celery?

Tags: celery, pytest, pytest-cov

I am using Pytest to test a Python application with:

pytest -s --cov=myApp

However a process of my App runs asynchronously with Celery. The test module runs the Celery process properly but I don't get any coverage information.

Is is possible to get coverage from a process ran by celery?

I had a look at [Celery testing](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/testing.html) but I don't want to test the asynchronously process directly/separately because I want to check how a process in MyAPP performs other actions with the task ID.

I also added the task module with --cov but I still don't get any coverage